# Expected error ':' on xcode game

Tags: objective-c

keep getting this error Expected ':'.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]SetInteger HighScoreforKey HighScoreSaved];
```

Comment: You gotta give us more to go on here.  List the line above it which also might contain the error.  What are these HighScoreforKey and HighScoreSaved things?  Stack Overflow is a great resource for newbs but you have to use it correctly to get help.

Comment: Maybe you should actually LOOK AT THE DOCUMENTATION for NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score -1):

Your declaration is wrong, change it like that below:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:HighScore forKey:HighScoreSaved];
```

Refer this [setInteger: forKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setInteger:forKey:) api for more details.